# Does "liege" mean master or servant?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity, dictionaries

Searching online, I see the two definitions for *liege* (noun) given by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/liege?show=2)

> 1. **a**: a vassal bound to feudal service and allegiance
>      **b**: a loyal subject
> 2. a feudal superior to whom allegiance and service are due

So, how are you supposed to identify which meaning being referred when you say "My liege"? Or is my understanding flawed in some way?

Comment: Context determines it. Though I have to say I don’t recall ever hearing “My liege” used to refer to the vassal; it’s too parallel to “My lord”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the second definition listed, therefore less used. I don't believe it is ambiguous in common usage. But as @JanusBahsJacquet says, context is king.

To be absolutely unambiguous, you can use "liege lord" and "liegeman" to refer up and down the allegiance train respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Wow? I would never have guessed that. My OED only mentions "a king or lord".
Still, it seems safe to assume people would always interpret "my liege" as being said by a servant to their master.

Comment: The online edition of the OED gives it as definition B.2: "A vassal bound to serve his superior, a liege man. Hence in a wider sense: A loyal subject of the king." It says "This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1903)". It might be helpful if you mentioned which edition yours is.

Answer (score 0):

It is very confusing, but it ***might*** help to read *liege lord* somewhat akin to *slave master*, except that *liege* carries a sense more like *slavery* than *slave* in that phrase.

A little bit like *college teacher* and *college student*, or *foreman* and *man*.